# How to save to a local variable and run a function in short circuit operand?

Tags: java, parsing, short-circuiting

I'm implementing a Recursive Descent parser for binary arithmetic. When doing backtracking, I do it by falling back to a saved pointer, but doing it with short circuit AND (`&&`) operation seems impossible. The following is the current implementation using global variables `save` and `next` and I realized it is wrong because single `save` will be overwritten by following saves.

```
/* 
 *
 * COMPILE : javac .\RecursiveDescentParse.java
 * RUN : java RecursiveDescentParse
 * compile and run : javac .\RecursiveDescentParse.java -Xlint:deprecation; java RecursiveDescentParse
 *
 * Unambiguous grammer for Binary Arithmetic
 *          E -> T | T + E
 *          T -> int | int * T | ( E )
 * 
 * Example token stream for grammer:
 *          (int) 
 *          OPEN INT CLOSE
 *          
 *          (int + int) * int 
 *          TOKEN.OPEN, TOKEN.INT, TOKEN.PLUS ,TOKEN.INT, TOKEN.CLOSE, TOKEN.TIMES, TOKEN.INT
 * 
 *          int * int + int
 *          TOKEN.INT, TOKEN.TIMES ,TOKEN.INT, TOKEN.PLUS, TOKEN.INT
 */

enum TOKEN{
    INT,    // int
    OPEN,   // (
    CLOSE,  // )
    PLUS,   // +
    TIMES   // *
}

public class RecursiveDescentParse{

    // pointing to the start token of the token stream
    public static int next = 0;

    // saving next pointer for backtracking
    public static int save;

    public static TOKEN[] tokenStream = new TOKEN[]{ TOKEN.INT, TOKEN.TIMES ,TOKEN.INT, TOKEN.PLUS, TOKEN.INT };

    static boolean term(TOKEN token){
        return tokenStream[next++] == token;
    }

    // E -> T
    static boolean E1(){ 
        return T(); 
    }

    // E -> T + E
    static boolean E2(){ 
        return T() && term(TOKEN.PLUS) && E(); 
    }

    // E -> T | T + E
    static boolean E(){ 
        // save pointer before incrementing cause guessing may be incorrect
        save = next;
        return (backtrack() & E1()) || (backtrack() & E2());
    }

    // T -> int
    static boolean T1(){
        return term(TOKEN.INT);
    }

    // T -> int * T
    static boolean T2(){
        return term(TOKEN.INT) && term(TOKEN.TIMES) && T(); 
    }

    // T -> ( E )
    static boolean T3(){
        return term(TOKEN.OPEN) && E() && term(TOKEN.CLOSE);
    }

    // T -> int | int * T | ( E )
    static boolean T(){
        save = next;
        return (backtrack() & T1()) || (backtrack() & T2()) || (backtrack() & T3());
    }

    static boolean backtrack(){
        next = save;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // start parsing the token stream
        System.out.println("Parsing status : " + E());
    }

}
```

I need to define local variables inside `E()` and `T()` as I could restore `next` by local `save` when left operand returns `false` in left operand of `&&`. I want to do something like below. How can I do that with short-circuiting? 
Thanks in advance!!

```
static boolean T(){
        int save = next;
        return (next = save, T1()) || (next = save, T2()) || (next = save, T3());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 (or higher), you can write a wrapper method as below, which will first restore the `next` variable and then invoke the actual method.

```
static boolean resetNextAndExecute(int savedNext, Supplier<Boolean> function) {
    next = savedNext;
    return function.get();
}
```

Then your `T()` method can be changed as follows.

```
static boolean T(){
    int save = next;
    return resetNextAndExecute(save, RecursiveDescentParse::T1) || resetNextAndExecute(save, RecursiveDescentParse::T2) || resetNextAndExecute(save, RecursiveDescentParse::T3);
}
```